# djangocms 3.2 page level

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I've upgraded a django-cms powered application from 2.4 to 3.2 and want show the submenu of a djangocms Page like this:

```
{% extends "layouts/base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags menu_tags %}

{% block 'content' %}
  {% with page_lvl=request.current_page.level %}
    {% show_sub_menu 1 page_lvl 1 'menues/cms_submenu.html' %}
  {% endwith %}
{% endblock %}
```

However, current_page.level seems to be None - this code worked in 2.4, but it seems that page no longer has a .level attribute. Where did it go to?

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/how_to/menus.html#navigation-modifiers  - there is even an example for a "Level" modifier.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. This is for mapping a page attribute to the corresponding but more lightweight node object - but since there is no Page.level any more, there is nothing to map, or did I miss something completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, DjangoCMS switched from MPTTTree [to Treebeard](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/4928). As a result, the information is now stored in the .depth attribute instead .level - but there is an offset compared to .level of 1 (so .level 3 is now .depth 4).